# Не получается передать переменную в тело запроса

Tags: javascript, rest, postman

Использую postman для rest тестирования.

В headers установлен Content-Type application/json.

Столкнулся с проблемой при передаче запроса с переменной, postman не считает ее таковой и отправляет все в тексте.

Во вкладке тест написан следующий код:

```js
pm.test("Status is ok, response is json", function () {
    pm.response.to.be.ok; // проверка статуса
    pm.response.to.be.json; // проверка формата
});

var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("tokenManual", data.token);
//Переменная trap в дальнейшем будет использована в теле
var trap = 1;
trap++;
```

В теле запроса написано следующее:

```js
{
 "login":"user_{{trap}}@example.com",
 "password":"password", 
 "acc_type": "account"
}
```

Ответ от сервера 400, логин уже использован.